# react redux saga does not put action

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to implement the following-
Users can login, but after 5 seconds they are being automatically logged out.
I work with JSONWEBTOKEN tho.

This is my try using redux sagas with react:

`app.ts` file (root of store):

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore, Reducer } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import * as fromAuth from './reducers/auth';

import { watchAuth } from './sagas/auth';

export interface AppState {
  auth: fromAuth.State;
}

const composeEnhancers: typeof compose = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const rootReducer: Reducer<AppState> = combineReducers({
  auth: fromAuth.reducer,
});

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)));

sagaMiddleware.run(watchAuth);
```

saga file:

```
import { ForkEffect, put, select, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import * as fromApp from '../app';
import * as authActions from '../actions/auth';

// --- Workers (Effects) --- //

function* loginSaga() {
  const logoutTimeoutCreationDate: string | null = yield localStorage.getItem('logoutTimeoutCreationDate');

  let logoutTimeout: number;

  if (
    !logoutTimeoutCreationDate ||
    new Date(logoutTimeoutCreationDate).getTime() + 5000 < new Date().getTime()
  ) {
    yield localStorage.setItem('logoutTimeoutCreationDate', new Date().toISOString());

    logoutTimeout = yield 5000;
  } else {
    logoutTimeout = yield new Date(logoutTimeoutCreationDate).getTime() + 5000 - new Date().getTime();
  }

  const newTimeout: NodeJS.Timeout = yield setTimeout(() => put(authActions.logout()), logoutTimeout);
  yield put(authActions.setLogoutTimeout(newTimeout));
}

function* logoutSaga() {
  const timeout: NodeJS.Timeout = yield select((state: fromApp.AppState) => state.auth.logoutTimeout);

  yield clearTimeout(timeout);
  yield sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
  yield localStorage.removeItem('logoutTimeoutCreationDate');

  yield put(authActions.setLogoutTimeout(null));
}

// --- Watchers --- //

export function* watchAuth():IterableIterator<ForkEffect>{
  yield takeEvery(authActions.AUTH_LOGIN, loginSaga);
  yield takeEvery(authActions.AUTH_LOGOUT, logoutSaga);
}
```

Reducer file:

```
import * as actions from '../actions/auth';
import { IUser } from '../../models/user';

export interface State {
  user: IUser | null;
  logoutTimeout: NodeJS.Timeout | null;
}

const initialState: State = {
  user: null,
  logoutTimeout: null,
};

export const reducer = (state: State = initialState, action: actions.AuthTypes): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.AUTH_LOGOUT:
      return { ...state, user: null };
    case actions.AUTH_LOGIN:
      return { ...state, user: action.payload.user };
    case actions.AUTH_SET_LOGOUT_TIMEOUT:
      return { ...state, logoutTimeout: action.payload.timeout };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

actions file:

```
import { IUser } from '../../models/user';

export const AUTH_LOGOUT = '[Auth] Logout';
export const AUTH_LOGIN = '[Auth] Login';
export const AUTH_SET_LOGOUT_TIMEOUT = '[Auth] Set logout timeout';

// --- Interface --- //

export interface Logout {
  type: typeof AUTH_LOGOUT;
}

export interface Login {
  type: typeof AUTH_LOGIN;
  payload: { user: IUser };
}

export interface SetLogoutTimeout {
  type: typeof AUTH_SET_LOGOUT_TIMEOUT;
  payload: { timeout: NodeJS.Timeout | null };
}

// --- Action creators --- //

export const logout = (): Logout => {
  return {
    type: AUTH_LOGOUT,
  };
};

export const login = (user: IUser): Login => {
  return {
    type: AUTH_LOGIN,
    payload: { user },
  };
};

export const setLogoutTimeout = (timeout: NodeJS.Timeout | null): SetLogoutTimeout => {
  return {
    type: AUTH_SET_LOGOUT_TIMEOUT,
    payload: { timeout },
  };
};

export type AuthTypes = Logout | Login | SetLogoutTimeout;
```

I believe `IUser` code is irrelevant for this question so I've omitted it.

The problem is, that once I log in, the line inside `loginSaga` function (in sagas file),
  `const newTimeout: NodeJS.Timeout = yield setTimeout(() => put(authActions.logout()), logoutTimeout);`
this works, but nothing happens with `put(authActions.logout())`. like I'vent wrote it.

I also use `redux devtools` and no action was emitted after 5 seconds. why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused about your environment here, or perhaps you're confused?  You are using DOM/window functions but you have the TypeScript type declared as `NodeJS.Timeout`.  That type [is an object](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/) but calling `setTimeout` in the browser returns [a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

It seems like you are storing the timeout in both `localStorage` and in your state.  I don't think *either* of those is necessary because saga has a built-in [`delay`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#delayms-val) effect to handle this task.

This is all you need:

```
import { ForkEffect, put, takeEvery, delay } from "redux-saga/effects";
import * as authActions from "./actions";

function* loginSaga() {
  yield delay(5000);
  yield put(authActions.logout());
}

export function* watchAuth(): IterableIterator<ForkEffect> {
  yield takeEvery(authActions.AUTH_LOGIN, loginSaga);
}
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-saga-auto-logout-user-dmhf6?file=/src/store/saga.ts)